# Overwrite with last entry in .txt Python 3

Tags: python

I'm writing this to show on OBS the player (in SC2) and opponent playing, but i only want the last game played, how can i overwrite the txt file so i keep only the last entry?

```
import requests;
import json;
import time;

def players():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:6119/game/');
    sc2data = json.loads(r.content)
    player = sc2data['players']
    playersname = (player[0]['name'],player[0]['race'], " vs ",player[1]['name'],player[1]['race'])
    print(playersname)
    print(playersname, file=open("output.txt", "a"))
    time.sleep(15)
x = 1
while True:
    players()
    x+=1
```

Comment: Not completely clear on what you're asking. `output.txt` should only ever contain one outcome? You could open in `w` mode which wipes the file each time and write the latest score, which can be read in the next time the game starts. Atm I don't see you reading or writing to the file?

Comment: Thanks, the 'w' worked, i'm printing the players name and race in output.txt.

Comment: There's anyway to remove those " ' ", from the out put? I'm getting something like this 

('IIIIIIIIIIII', 'Prot', ' vs ', 'A.I. 1 (Very Easy)', 'Zerg')

Comment: I don't know what part you're referring to? Is that the printed output, the thing written to file (that you haven't included in the code)?